# Swift 4 How to segue from a view controller to a sks secene

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, sprite-kit, uikit

I have ran into a wall when using UIKit and SpriteKit. I currently segue from a sks scene to view controller and i have no clue on how to go from a view controller to a brand new sks scene. Please help.

Comment: Show some codes that you have tried. So people can know where to help.

Answer (score 2):

use presentScene()

For example if you were showing a main menu scene it would look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var skView: SKView?
  var mainMenu: MainMenu?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    skView = self.view as! SKView?
  }

  func showMainMenu() {
    //You should probably deallocate any scenes you have in memory here
    mainMenu = MainMenu(fileNamed: "MainMenu")
    mainMenu?.scaleMode = .fill
    skView!.presentScene(mainMenu)
  }
}


class MainMenu: SKScene {
  override func willMove(from view: SKView) {
    removeAllChildren() //When moving from the scene again remember to clear up memory
  }
}
```